# Implement std::ops::Add for a trait

Tags: generics, rust, operator-overloading

I have a trait like this:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

pub trait GroupElement: Clone + Sized {
    fn plus(&self, b: &Self) -> Self;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct G1 {
    value: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct G2 {
    value: i32,
}

impl GroupElement for G1 {
    fn plus(&self, b: &Self) -> Self {
        let value = self.value + b.value;
        G1 { value }
    }
}

impl GroupElement for G2 {
    fn plus(&self, b: &Self) -> Self {
        let value = self.value + b.value;
        G2 { value }
    }
}
```

Now if I wanted to overload the `+` operator without code duplication I could use a macro to implement the `Add` trait like this

```rust
impl Add for $group_element {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self {
        self.plus(&other)
    }
}
```

But I want to implement `Add` for the trait `GroupElement` so that I can use the generic functions over `GroupElement` by using the `+` operator.

```rust
impl<T: GroupElement> Add<T> for GroupElement {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: T) -> Self {
        self.plus(&other)
    }
}
```

Above code comlains about GroupElement not having a known size at compile time which I agree with, different groups will have different sizes.

I tried the following code

```rust
impl<T: GroupElement> Add<T> for T {
    type Output = T;

    fn add(self, other: T) -> T {
        self.plus(&other)
    }
}
```

I get error with message `` type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type `` which seems incorrect since `GroupElement` is local to my crate.

How should I solve this? The actual implementation of GroupElement is [here](https://github.com/lovesh/amcl_rust_wrapper/blob/master/src/group_elem.rs#L21). Links to [G1](https://github.com/lovesh/amcl_rust_wrapper/blob/master/src/group_elem_g1.rs#L20) and [G2](https://github.com/lovesh/amcl_rust_wrapper/blob/master/src/group_elem_g2.rs#L21).

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256519/i-implemented-a-trait-for-another-trait-but-cannot-call-methods-from-both-traits). But it seems like you already figured out how to correctly do that. The problem here seems to stem from *orphan rules*. This might be a term to search for.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt The orphan rule applies when the trait and type are in different crates which is not the case here.

Comment: That is the case here as you implement `for T` which could be any type. Yes, the type has to implement `GroupElement` (which is from your crate), but people could depend on your crate and implement `GroupElement` for their types. So indeed orphan rules are the problem here. But I understand why it doesn't seem like a problem (especially so if `GroupElement` is private or your crate is an executable). [This RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.md) which relaxes the rules a bit could help you, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: Well, you can always do it with a macro. The syntax in `impl Add for $group_element` even looks like one (due to the `$`)…