# What does it mean to implement a trait for another trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256519/i-implemented-a-trait-for-another-trait-but-cannot-call-methods-from-both-traits) but I'm still confused.

1. How do you interpret `impl B for dyn A {}`?

   ```
   trait A {
       fn method_a(&self) {
           println!("a");
       }
   }

   trait B {
       fn method_b(&self) {
           println!("b")
       }
   }

   impl B for dyn A {}

   impl A for i32 {}

   fn main() {
       let x: &dyn A = &10;
       x.method_b();
   }
   ```

   [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aff44ea7d1238fb32e58cfef93fed4a5)

   I can understand `impl A for i32 {}` because `i32` is a concrete type. `dyn A` is not a concrete type (unsized, can't pass by value), and you cannot declare a `dyn A` but you can only declare a `&dyn A`. Should I interpret

   ```
   // x.method_b();
   (*x).method_b();
   ```

   as `*x` is `dyn A`?
2. I can also declare `impl B for &dyn A {}`, so why I need `impl B for dyn A {}`? What's the use case?
3. Follow up: If I modify the code

   ```
   fn main() {
       let x: &dyn A = &10;
       // have a B trait object over dyn A since
       // dyn A implements B
       let y: &dyn B = x;  
   }
   ```

   It will fail and complain `&dyn A` is not `&dyn B`. I understand this is a reasonable complain but I provide the option for compiler to use `impl B for dyn A {}`. Apparently, the compiler doesn't consider that's an option.

Comment: also posted and answered in Rust forum: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-does-it-mean-to-implement-trait-for-trait/44031?u=jarvi-izana

Comment: update: an inlined, super detailed answer. https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-does-it-mean-to-implement-trait-for-trait/44031/2?u=jarvi-izana

Answer (score 5):

You can't declare `dyn A` but you can declare `&dyn A` because `dyn A` is a trait object *type* while `&dyn A` is a *pointer* to an instance of type `T` that implements `A`.

Historically, a trait could be used as a type and a trait. For instance, these both work:

```
// Where B and A are traits
impl B for A {}
impl B for dyn A {}
```

Basically, `dyn A` is just a sugar over `A` to make it clearer that it is meant to be used as a trait object type. **You don't implement a trait for another trait. You implement a trait for another trait object type**.

`&dyn A` is a pointer instance to an instance of type `T` that implements `A` and a virtual method table (vtable), which contains all the baggage of methods of `A` that `T` implements. This vtable lookup is necessary when an instance of type `T` later calls `A`'s implementation at runtime.

Therefore, `dyn A` is an unsized type while `&dyn A` is a pointer with a known size.

Trait object of type `dyn A` must be cast from a pointer to be used as a concrete type that implements `A`. For example, in the code example, `i32` can be cast to a `dyn A`:

```
impl B for dyn A {}

impl A for i32 {}

fn main() {
    let x: i32 = 10;
    (&x as &dyn A).method_a(); 
    (&x as &dyn A).method_b();
}
```

or it can be coerced by a function:

```
fn dispatch(a: &dyn A) {
    a.method_b();
}
```

Because traits are dynamically sized types (DSTs), to use them as trait objects, we must put them behind some kind of pointer, like `&dyn A` or `Box<dyn A>` so it can point to a variable-sized value and access the vtable to call the implemented methods.

See also: [What makes something a “trait object”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27570064/1965774)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's better for you to explain `(*x).method_b();`.  I totally agree with the `trait object type` explanation (I will give you thumb up for that). But for `impl B for dyn A {}` explanation. I found this https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-does-it-mean-to-implement-trait-for-trait/44031/2?u=jarvi-izana is great. I'd like to share with you.